# Download URL of blackberry JDK not working, new URL?

Tags: blackberry

The Software update url for eclipse to get the JDK plugin for blackberry does not seem to be working.

http://www.blackberry.com/go/eclipseUpdate

Is there a new URL to use?

Comment: this url is working fine which version of eclipse you are using.
if you are using 3.5 version use this url
http://www.blackberry.com/go/eclipseUpdate/3.5/java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one (have to fill in some in formation):

https://www.blackberry.com/Downloads/contactFormPreload.do?code=DC727151E5D55DDE1E950767CF861CA5&dl=F8D6D0BA2E24A29A759368B68241E7F5

Comment: Thanks for the URL. I was actually hoping to do in the Eclipse through the "software update". Is that no longer possible?

Comment: you could try this sir:

http://www.blackberry.com/go/eclipseUpdate/3.5/java

But the server sometimes give you 0 bytes size zip file which screws up the installation. Presumably because the server is too busy? I'd say the standalone download is safer.

Comment: and you may find this link useful: http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/javaappdev/javaplugin.jsp

Comment: Thanks Viele, that URL turned out to work.  blackberry.com/go/eclipseUpdate/3.5/java. Too bad it wasn't documented anywhere on the Blackberry site.